# I am getting following error while installing pyswmm. "error: package directory 'bin' does not exist"

Tags: python, watershed

I am getting following error while installing pyswmm.  "error: package directory 'bin' does not exist"

`[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufwYS.png)

I tried to install pyswmm but getting error message.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using python 3.10 from winpython.

The solution for me was to use python 3.9 that I had installed in anaconda environment.

I hope this can help you.